# Input data during import to both tables with CSV mapping

Tags: php

I've simple script, CSV import  with column mapping.

I post mapping column to this function:

```
if(isset($_POST["sku"]))
{
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=feed_import", "feed_import", "tSpIn35M");

 session_start();

 $file_data = $_SESSION['file_data'];

 unset($_SESSION['file_data']);

 foreach($file_data as $row)
 {
  $data[] = '("'.$row[$_POST["sku"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["category_id"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["price"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["discount_rate"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["vat_rate"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["stock"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["external_link"]].'")';
 }

 if(isset($data))
 {
  $query = "
  INSERT INTO products
  (sku, category_id, price, discount_rate, vat_rate, stock, external_link) 
  VALUES ".implode(",", $data)."
  ";

  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

  if($statement->execute())
  {
   echo 'Data Imported Successfully';
  }
 }
}
```

Currently I insert data only to one table "products"

```
sku, category_id, price, discount_rate, vat_rate, stock, external_link
```

What is issue?

- besides, it needs to post two extra values "description" and "title" and add it to the second  table `product_details`

I can exteand this function:

```
$data[] = '("'.$row[$_POST["sku"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["category_id"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["price"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["discount_rate"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["vat_rate"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["stock"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["external_link"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["title"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["description"]].'")';
```

But how to correct build query?

```
$query = "
      INSERT INTO products
      (sku, category_id, price, discount_rate, vat_rate, stock, external_link) 
      VALUES ".implode(",", $data)."
      ";
```

Comment: You'll need a separate query to insert to your second table.

Comment: You can not keep using `VALUES ".implode(",", $data)`, if you add those extra columns to your $data array - because then the number of values, will not match the number of columns you specified any more. Collect these fields in an extra array, and use that one in your second INSERT statement then.